# Django Rest creating Nested-Objects (ManyToMany)

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework

I looked for an answer to this question specifically for Django Rest, but I haven't found one anywhere, although I think a lot of people have this issue. I'm trying to create an object with multiple nested relationships but something is keeping this from happening.  Here are my models for reference:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, null=True)
    tmp_password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user.username)

class Item(models.Model):
"""Item Object Class"""
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/", blank=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    photo_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    item_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)


class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user.username)

    def admin_names(self):
        return '\n'.join([a.name for a in self.items.all()])
```

And here are my serializers:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'description', 'rating', 'photo', 'barcode', 'photo_url','item_url' )


class FavoriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Favorite
        exclude = ('id', 'user')


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('likes', 'dislikes', 'photo', 'tmp_password')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    userprofile = UserProfileSerializer()
    favorite = FavoriteSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 'username', 'url',
             'email', 'is_staff', 'password',
             'userprofile', 'favorite'
             )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofile')
        favorites_data = validated_data.pop('favorite')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        favorite = Favorite(user=user)
        favorite.save()
        print favorite.items
        for item in favorites_data:
            favorite.items.add(item)
        print favorite.items
        return user
```

What I am having trouble with is the `create()` method on `UserSerializer`. What's happening is I can't `.add()` the data from `favorites_data` to the `favorite` object. I get an error saying `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'items'`.  I guess this makes sense, but if I try this instead of using the for loop:

```
favorite.items.add(**favorites_data)
```

I just get an error saying `add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'items'`.  Finally, If I try this:

```
favorite.items.add(favorites_data)
```

I just get this error: `unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'`

What am I doing wrong in this approach?  Obviously, `favorites_data` exist, but I'm not inserting it properly.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you give us the contents of `favorites_data` is?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Here it is: `OrderedDict([(u'items', [<Item: item>])])` . It is the contents of the item I select to populate the `favorite` field of `UserSerializer` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `favorite.items.add` expects you to pass in a single instance of an `Item`, so you should replace this:

```
for item in favorites_data:
    favorite.items.add(item)
```

With this:

```
for key in favorites_data:
    for item in favorites_data[key]:
        favorite.items.add(item)
```

Comment: this is super close, but only the nth item is being added, even when selecting multiple options.

Comment: Actually your answer might be right. Only one instance of item is coming in the validated data, even when choosing multiple options... which is kind of odd